# Will cap staples used to secure house wrap cause hardie plank to bulge?

Tags: siding

Contractor told me cap staples I told him to use for house wrap may cause noticeable bulges in the hardie plank. Is this a valid concern? Is there an acceptable height of irregularities like this that won't cause issues with Hardie Plank?

Comment: He's not lying -- hardie plank is pretty floppy, so can telegraph bulges. What made you want cap staples?